# how to load the XML file to Hbase using Storm

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-storm

i am trying to load data xml data which is comming for ActiveMQ and pushing into hbase  using the storm sample data is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoices>
<Invoice><InvoiceNo>12212</InvoiceNo><InvoiceDate>1/8/2015</InvoiceDate><CommodityName>ABC</CommodityName><Services>Goods</Services><NameOfPurchaser>Purchaser US</NameOfPurchaser></Invoice></Invoices>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose once you are in storm(a Hbase bolt kind of), and have a handle of xml, you can get the data and the elements in xml using jaxb. So as long as you have data, you can load it into Hbase with proper column families and qualifiers.

On the other side, you can always store the entire xml string into Hbase. Please think of how you want to use, Hbase and proceed.

Comment: thanks for your update, but i am still confused can you explain this with an example